# What type should I store a csv file as in a Rails 3.2 database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv

As a part of my application, I need to store a csv file in a database but what field type should I set in the model to store the csv file. Is it a string type or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: don't.

Store it on the file system and put a reference to that path as a string field in your database. When you need to load the file, perform a `File.read` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store it in some kind of array.

For example, `arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")` returns an array of arrays ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-read)).

You can store this in the database using the `serialize` method. This requires that you use the `text` rails data type.